# Communication Between Unrelated Objects

Tags: objective-c, macos, sprite-kit, event-handling, delegation

#### Background

I'm creating a rhythm app for MIDI drumming using SpriteKit on Mac OS. `Note` objects are the ones in green and blue below. The notes move from right to left on the screen. As the notes get closer to the "play bar" in red, I want to create an outline of the notes next to the play bar to indicate to the user that the notes are getting close to the play bar and that it's time to play soon.

[image: Mock-up of rhythm app]

#### The Problem

I need each `Note` object to notify another class called `Sequencer` when they get a certain distance from the play head so that it can start the note outline animation for the closest note. The notes know how far they are from the play head, so that's not a problem. **Would delegation be a candidate for this situation?** I have tried to understand the purpose of delegation, but I can never figure out how to implement it into my specific game-related situation.

**EDIT: Code added**

**GameScene.m**

```
@implementation GameScene

- (void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    ...
    [self initSequence];
    [self initNoteProcessor];
    [self initPlayBar];
    ...
}

...

//keeps track of a collection of notes and vertical line measure markers and
//responsible for drawing them in scene and moving them left
-(void) initSequence {
    _sequence = [[Sequencer alloc] initWithWidth:1150];
    [_sequence setPosition:CGPointMake(130, 0)];
    [self addChild:_sequence];
}
...

//responsible for handling incoming MIDI input from a keyboard and checking to see
//if notes are played on time, early or late
-(void) initNoteProcessor {
    _noteProcessor = [[NoteProcessor alloc] initWithSequence:_sequence];
}
...
//creates a vertical line that indicates when notes need to be played
-(void) initPlayBar {
    _playBar = (SKSpriteNode*)[self childNodeWithName:@"playBar"];
    _playBar.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:_playBar.frame.size];
    _playBar.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
    [_playBar.physicsBody setDynamic:YES];
    [_playBar.physicsBody setAllowsRotation:NO];
    [_playBar.physicsBody setCategoryBitMask:kPlayBarCategory];
    [_playBar.physicsBody setCollisionBitMask:kNoCategory];
    [_playBar.physicsBody setContactTestBitMask:kNoteCategory | kLineCategory];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setDouble:_playBar.position.x forKey:@"playBarXPosition"];
}
```

**NoteProcessor.m**

```
@implementation NoteProcessor

-(instancetype) initWithSequence:(Sequencer*)sequence {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _sequence = sequence;
        _noteActiveIndex = 0;
        [self initActiveNoteIndices];
        [self initNoteIndicator];

        //when user plays key on keyboard, notify this class
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(midiPlayed:) name:@"MidiPlayedNotificationKey" object:nil];

    }
    return self;
}

//keeps track of the next note of each pitch that is incoming
-(void) initActiveNoteIndices {
    _activeNoteIndicesByPitch = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i = 0; i < kTotalKeys; i++) {
        [_activeNoteIndicesByPitch addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:0]];
    }
}

//checks position of note and decides whether they are on time, early or late
-(void) updateCurrentNoteStatus {
    ...
}

//handles notifications from MIDI keyboard when user plays a key
-(void) midiPlayed:(NSNotification*)notification {
     //stuff happens here
}


@end
```

**Sequencer.m**

```
@implementation Sequencer

-(instancetype) initWithWidth:(double)width {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        ...

        [self drawNotes];
    }
    return self;
}

//draws all of the notes on screen
-(void) drawNotes {
    NSMutableArray *parsedNotes = [_midiParser getNoteData];
    float distancePerBeat = [self getGridArea] / [self getMeasuresDisplayed] / 4;
    float xPos = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < [parsedNotes count]; i++) {
        NSArray *currNote = [parsedNotes objectAtIndex:i];
        double location = [[currNote objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue];
        double duration = [[currNote objectAtIndex:1] doubleValue];
        int midiValue = [[currNote objectAtIndex:2] intValue];

        Note *note = [[Note alloc] initWithLocation:location Duration:duration MidiValue:midiValue];
        xPos = distancePerBeat * (location - 1);
        float yPos = kNoteHeight[note.midiValue - 36];
        [note setPosition:CGPointMake(xPos, yPos)];
        [note setZPosition:kNoteZPosition];

        NSMutableArray *noteList = [_notes objectAtIndex:midiValue-36];
        [noteList addObject:note];
        [self addChild:note];
    }
}

//this method is called 60 times per second
//each call moves 1/60th of the distance it would move in 1/60th of a second
-(void) moveLeftAfterElapsedTime:(double)elapsedTime {
    double timePerBeat = 60 / [self getBpm];
    double timePerMeasure = timePerBeat * 4;

    double lengthPerMeasure = [self getGridArea] / [self getMeasuresDisplayed];
    double distancePerFrame = lengthPerMeasure / (timePerMeasure * 60);

    double x = elapsedTime * distancePerFrame * 60;

    [self moveAllNotesLeftByDistance:x];
}

//actually does all of the moving of the notes
-(void) moveAllNotesLeftByDistance:(double)distance {
    for (int i = 0; i < [_notes count]; i++) {
        NSMutableArray *noteList = [_notes objectAtIndex:i];
        for (int j = 0; j < [noteList count]; j++) {
            Note *note = [noteList objectAtIndex:j];
            double xPos = note.position.x - distance;
            double y = note.position.y;

            [note setPosition:CGPointMake(xPos, y)];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would not use delegation, like the word suggests, it's when you get someone else to do something for you. In this case Note's don't need to know or care what is done with the information about its distance. Use notificaiton. Let Sequencer listen for notifications and have Notes send notifcations when the distance is right.

Comment: You do not want notifications either,  notifications are like sending out a message on a walkie talkie, anyone with the frequency can listen in.  Without code it is hard to say what to do exactly, but there should be some kind of manager handling both notes and sequence.  I am going to assume this is GameScene.  GameScene should be looking at note, and then telling sequence that it is up

Comment: Ok. I've used notifications before. I've read some sites that say it's bad because of traceability and stuff like that, which is why I've started looking into delegation and other solutions. It's tricky because I know what I want my code to do, but I don't know how to articulate that in code without making it messier. Trying to keep your code organized is a chore! Thanks for the response.

Comment: Give all your objects a specific job.  The notes job should not be to tell somebody they are getting close.  The notes job should be to do whatever it is a note does.  Somebody else should be playing switchboard, and communicating when to do certain events,  these are called managers.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I'll post some code above and explain what the classes are responsible for so far. As you've said, I try to give all of my classes a single task to complete.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Code has been added. I hope it's clear. I removed a lot of the details because they're probably not all that helpful.

Comment: Welcome to why oop sucks 101. Should the note animate itself, or should something else animate the note? You get more and more philosophical questions like this the deeper you go. Make a plain function somewhere, explicitly pass in all of the arguments, and have someone call it (perhaps GameScene). Boom, problem solved. Procedural power :)

Comment: Lol, I hear you. Doesn't that also produce high coupling? I swear programming things takes so long because you're always trying to future proof your code so that it's robust and lightweight, etc. This will definitely be my last resort if I don't discover some other technique.

Comment: If the sequencer is drawing notes what is the need to tell the sequencer the position of notes as it already knows.